# Vega-lite geojson: only identity projection works, otherwise only shows last feature

Tags: javascript, visualization, geojson, vega-lite

I'm trying to visualise the World Bank Official Boundaries:World Boundaries GeoJSON - Low Resolution data from https://datacatalog.worldbank.org/dataset/world-bank-official-boundaries with vega-lite.

However, it looks like only the last feature is displayed, with all others ignored. For example:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "width": 630,
  "height": 630,
  "data": {
    "url": "/map",
    "format": {"property": "features"}
  },
  "projection": {
    "type": "mercator"
  },
  "mark": {
    "type": "geoshape",
    "stroke": "black",
    "strokeWidth": 0.5
  }
}
```

seems to only display New Zealand, which I think is the last feature in the file:

[image]

[A similar example that has the same problem and includes only data for New Zealand and one other country before can be seen in a gist](https://gist.github.com/michalc/4885b28e6156330103d17416ca873018)

If I change the projection to 'identity', then that projection seems to work as expected.

How can I get all the features to display in vega-lite in a non-identity projection?

Comment: The data I believe you're referring to is a collection of a few geojson files - coastlines, country boundaries, land, disputed areas etc. Are you looking for a specific layer, or some combination of layers ? Your code works fine with e.g. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the coordinates of World Bank barrier JSON don't have a winding order that vega-lite interprets properly.  I suspect this makes it think some islands are lakes, and puts the land outside them rather than inside.

Using https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-rewind fixed it:

```
geojson-rewind --clockwise WB_countries_Admin0_lowres.geojson > WB_countries_Admin0_lowres-clockwise.geojson
```

[image]